# Writing JSON object to file and getting null written instead

Tags: json, python-3.x, writetofile

I'm using Python to create a data.json file and write a json object to it.

```py
with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        util.json.dump(jsonData, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

where `jsonData = {'Book': {'author': 'John Black', 'description': 'When....`

When I locate data.json file on my computer and open it to modify the content, instead of  `{'Book': {'author':...` I see `null` printed in the file.
I don't understand why it is happening, jsonData is not null, I printed it out before manipulating to double-check.
Thank you for your help in advance! =)

Comment: what i s 'jsonData'?  Can you paste the full code what you are doing ?

Comment: Can't figure out why use `util.json.dump`. Just using `json.dump()` works fine here

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what purpose `util` is fulfilling here but using `json` library seems to be giving right results.

```
import json

jsonData = {'Book': {'author': 'John Black', 'description': 'When....'}}

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(jsonData, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
jsonData = {
    "Book": {
        "author": "ohn Black",
        "description": "afasffsaf afafasfsa"
    }
}

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   f.write(json.dumps(jsonData))
```